# 20.04 - Visual artifacts in Gnome - frames of other windows' elements

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. Lenovo [ThinkPad T540 (tech spec)](https://support.lenovo.com/bg/en/solutions/pd100413), graphics card `Intel HD Graphics 4600 in processor`.

The upgrade did not go well - the display got stuck for too long (hours), so I rebooted. The upgrade was incomplete and I had to reconfigure all packages, after which it booted again.

However, there is one big annoyance: Across all desktop, I keep seeing visual artifacts, flickering 1px lines or 1px rectangles, which sometimes seem to match some panes of the windows in the background.

For instance, if I have Oracle VirtualBox manager window open in the background, and Firefox in the front, then I keep seeing the frames of VirtualBox's UI elements on Firefox'es window.

Is there something I can try to get rid of this?
Assuming it may have something to do with the failed upgrade, should I re-install / re-configure something?

Comment: You should mention the graphics card you are using. Still, in case an upgrade went badly, I would first start with a fresh install, and only look to solve graphical issues if these persist in a fresn install.

Comment: Possibly, I could do that, but a reinstallation will take me several days to set up desktop to what it was, while fixing may take just few minutes. My experiance with Linux is that even when things look very bad at the beginning, there's a couple of commands that fix it.  I'm upgrading this instance since around 2014.
Tech info added.